# Office 365 API Not All Events Being Received

Tags: outlook, office365, office365-restapi

I am using the Outlook Calendar REST API to retrieve calendar events.

When I call the url https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/users/#{email}/calendarview?endDateTime=2016-09-01T10:00&startDateTime=2016-08-10T10:00

I get only the single event instances returned. How can I include the occurrences of repeating events too?

Comment: So, did you figure out the reason or found any workaround?

Comment: No. I'm not sure if something changed at their end, but eventually these started to come through correctly for our calendars

Answer (score 0):

*The calendar view REST gets the occurrences, exceptions, and single instances of events in a calendar view defined by a time range*. It works well for me. Please check whether the time range is correct to filter the view.

In addition, you can check the type of event type in the response. It should be **Occurrence** in this scenario.

### Update: test with Microsoft Account

[image]

Comment: The time range is correct, there are single events and occurrences in the calendar that I am accessing.

Comment: Were you testing using the Office 365 account or the Microsoft account? I tested with the Office 365 account and it worked well.

Comment: I thought they were the same? In my development account I have setup an AD user, and can access both recurring and singular events. When I access the client's calendar I can only see the singular events. What is the difference between the two? Or how can I find out?

Comment: I was testing with the Microsoft Account again however it still worked well for me. I would share the result with you see the post above. Would you mind trying to reproduce this issue in another Microsoft Account?

Comment: Thanks Fei, I am trying using the office 365 account and recurrences are still not coming through correctly. I can see all events for any given day with the exception of the recurrences. Any ideas on what else to try?